# In linear mixed model, what if the dependent variable is repetitive for a random factor?

Tags: mixed-model

**(1) Research background:**

My research design involves having each participant complete multiple trials to assess their happiness rating while simultaneously recording EEG data. Each participant has different EEG channels. I aim to use EEG data metrics (such as avg_HFB and peri_HFB) from each channel to predict happiness ratings. Since participants underwent repeated measurements at different times, I constructed a linear mixed model with subject and channel as random variables. Channels are nested within subjects, and happiness rating (zrating) is the dependent variable, as follows:

`zrating ~ avg_HFB * peri_HFB + (1|subject/channels)`

**(2) Problem Encountered:**

However, during fitting, I encountered a singular fit issue where the variance of subject:channels was equal to 0.

[image]

**(3) Sample Data:**

Here is data structure and some example data:

[image]
[image]

There are about 15 participants, each with 1-8 channels, and 30-140 trials.

**(4) Attempts I have Made:**

1. In the linear mixed model, if the random factor includes only subject or channels, the model can be fitted successfully.

[image: picture2]

2. By duplicating the data for a few participants (approximately 600 observations), the nested model could be fitted.

[image]

**(5) My guess:**

For a given subject, the channels simutaneously recorded the EEG data while subjects are doing happyratings, which means that all channels of a subject correspond to the same set of dependent variable data (the happyrating data). Therefore, I assume that the variation in the dependent variable is only reflected between participants. Within the same participant, there might be no variation between channels (although the number of trials and specific trials may vary). If so, having either subject or channel as a random factor should be sufficient to capture this variability. Thus, I speculate that the reason for having only subject variance when both subject and channel are treated as random factors might be due to this.

The distribution of zratings across various channels for a given subject：
[image]

However, this is only my logical or intuitive speculation. I'm unsure if this reasoning is right, and it cannot explain why replicating the data allows the model to fit (as the data structure should remain unchanged). And another question is that, similar models in other literature are exactly specified as  `(1|subject/channels)`, I don't know how they can make it...

This is the first time that I ask a question on this platform, so if any further information is required, please let me know.

Thanks!

Thanks to BenP's suggestion, I tested the variation across channels in all subjects, and the result is as follows:

[image]

(There are 12 subjects instead of 13 since one of them has only one channel.)

The p value of subject2 is less than 0.05, so I checked the data:

[image]
[image]

It seems that it's because one of his channels contains different specific trials.

Comment: Please can you explain what this means *", within each subject, the dependent variables are the same dataset for different channels. (that's because in every trial of a subject, EEG data in different channels correspond to the same behavior index, which is the dependent variable)."* ?? Perhaps it will help if you show us an extract of your data, for instance the data for 1 subject.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have put some data in the description.

Comment: Thanks for adding that, but I'm sorry, I still don't understand the problem. You said *"Take a partial data of sub-a as an example, every channel records many same trials."*. What does this mean ? Also, please can you describe the study design and tell us your research question(s).

Comment: Sorry for confusing description and thanks again! I added more information.

Comment: Do I understand it right : you have different types of happiness ratings ? Because you write "for the same participant, each channel corresponds to the same set of dependent variable data (happiness ratings for many trials, although not identical for all trials)"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I understand you right, It's not different type, happyrating is a continuous variable, and a subject should do happyrating for many times(trials). The reason why "each channel corresponds to the same set of dependent variable data " is that these channels  simutaneously recorded the EEG data while subjects are doing happyratings.

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post, and not only as an comment. On this site we want posts to be self-contained, and comments are ephemeral and often not seen by many.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After answering the question as an comment, I actually also edited the post.

Comment: Your guess could be right. Did you check that, for each subject, the channel means of zrating show some variation? Maybe that the two means for sub-a are very very close and this could be the case for all subjects. In that case you may not even need different channels, one could be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I just tried that, which provided some information. I added the result in the post!

Comment: You're right, EEG data is complicated and exhibits complex temporal variations. But here, my independent variables are averaged across timepoints during happyrating, so it doesn't matter. What I want to explore is the overall effect of EEG data.

Comment: Looking again at (4) Attempts made, you say that you also used subject and channels separately; in the summaries shown I see both time 13 groups (subjects). It's unclear for me which models you precisely ran here and converged. Your Model3 had a "boundary fit", but the optimizer said "convergence code 0 (OK)". Just wondering what would happen if you would use ML instead of REML, or another optimizer. I have the impression that the results for your model3 are actually OK, meaning that there really is NO variance across channels within subjects.

Comment: Also, the total variance of all random effects is the same for you model3 and the other models shown in (4).

Comment: You showed an anova like table for the 7 channels, but that was not exactly what I meant. You have 13 subject, and I was wondering how the 7 channel means of subject 1 vary. And those of subject 2 etc. So a 13 by 7 table with mean values of zrating. My guess is that in each row there is hardly any variation.

Comment: You could also make the anova table for each subject, so 13 such tables in total. The proportion variance explained (SSQ channels / SSQ total) is very low in your table. If this would also be the case for each subject, this would confirm the idea of no or hardly any variance between channels within subjects. And that would be an argument to drop the variance in your model3.

Comment: Hi, BenP. Thanks so much for your suggestions! Firstly, I checked the attempt results, so sorry that I put the same picture for subject and channels by mistake. I have modified that. And about the anova across channels for each subject, I put the results in the post. There is exactly no variation across channels except for one subject. Yes... I guess that's the reason. But I'm not sure how the similar papers can make it. And my mentor also suggested me keeping  the nested model...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150459/discussion-between-eve-and-benp).

Comment: Would be OK for me, already went there